# Is it possible to show multiple displays in Android 3.x Emulator?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is it possible to display multiple displays in Android 3.x emulator?

I like to run multiple activities one on main display and the other on 2nd display. Just wondering if I can test in Android emulator.

Videoguy

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support multiple displays. Device manufacturers that have created dual-display devices have done so on their own. Hence, there is no way to use multiple displays with the emulator at this time.